# What does the phrase "cross your eyes" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence:

"Just cross your eyes a little and it would be impossible for you to tell the difference between this and televised football."

The sentence is from a game app's description. I know the lexical meaning of the phrase ["cross your eyes"](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/cross%20one's%20eyes).

> **Verb    1.**    cross one's eyes - partly close one's eyes;
> *"The children squinted to frighten each other"*
>   **Synonyms:** squint, squinch
>   <sub>[Webster](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/cross%20one's%20eyes)</sub>

However, I am not sure how it would fit here.

Let me make the context clearer. The sentence is about a game update that makes the mobile play so realistic that one cannot differentiate between the game and the real football.

Comment: The definition you posted of "cross your eyes" is wrong. That's probably the source of your confusion.

Comment: I edited out the totally incorrect definition, to avoid further massive confusion.

Comment: @Fattie: I think the edit changes the OP's intent. I am pretty sure the OP was wondering how squinting would help a video game appear to be a live game. My edit merely quoted the OP's link. My answer attempts to address the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 17):

Crossing your eyes makes it harder to see clearly. This usage means unless you are paying close attention to the differences between the two things, you won't notice them.

I haven't heard this expression used before, but in my personal experience, I have heard people say "if you squint hard enough..."

Comment: For what it's worth, squinting has the opposite effect. You would say, "If you squint hard enough you *can* tell the difference between this and televised football."

Comment: @JasonBassford usually it's used as "X looks like Y if you squint", which is indeed comparable to the eye-crossing analogy.

Comment: @Ketura To be clear, crossing your eyes and squinting are *not* the same thing—although the two are used in a syntactically similar fashion in the example of this question and answer. Crossing your eyes *blurs* your vision, meaning you *can't* see the difference; meanwhile, squinting *sharpens* your vision, meaning you *can* see the difference. You would not normally say *X looks like Y if you squint*. Rather X looks like Y when you *don't* squint because you can't distinguish between the two. Instead, you would simply say *You can* ***make out X*** *if you squint*.

Answer (score 2):

I have not personally encountered the usage of *cross your eyes* to mean squinting as indicated in your linked reference. I had always heard it used to mean making your eyes appear to be crossed. The condition ***esotropia*** is commonly referred to as being *cross-eyed*:

> **Esotropia** is a form of strabismus in which one or both eyes turns inward. The condition can be constantly present, or occur intermittently, and can give the affected individual a "cross-eyed" appearance.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esotropia)</sub>

You can usually accomplish crossing your eyes by trying to focus your eyes on the tip of your nose.

[image]

In addition to a funny looking face, you could get double vision, or lose focus, or something else, and thus have trouble seeing things clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing the expression "*screwed her eyes tight*" with the meaning that you're after here.

I would personally rewrite the sentence to something like

"*You'll actually mistake this for televised football if you don't pay enough attention*".

Answer (score 1):

It's that, when you cross your eyes, you lose depth perception. The comment is the equivalent of saying "It's almost like watching in HD;" or, in other words, it's not *quite as good visually, but could be if you lower your standards.*

As far as I'm aware, it's not a colloquial phrase anywhere in the US or GB, so whoever said this to you probably missed the intended purpose.